# reduction calculate sum of an array using cuda c

Tags: c++, cuda

I encounter a problem is that when I run my cuda programm, there is always saying that an illegal memory access was encountered in stats_gpu.cu at line 167.

The code is as following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cuda.h>

#define MAXIMUM_VALUE   1000000.0f
#define HANDLE_ERROR( err )  ( HandleError( err, __FILE__, __LINE__ ) )

void HandleError( cudaError_t err, const char *file, int line ) {
  //
  // Handle and report on CUDA errors.
  //
  if ( err != cudaSuccess ) {
    printf( "%s in %s at line %d\n", cudaGetErrorString( err ), file, line );

    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }
}

void checkCUDAError( const char *msg, bool exitOnError ) {
  //
  // Check cuda error and print result if appropriate.
  //
  cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();

  if( cudaSuccess != err) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Cuda error: %s: %s.\n", msg, cudaGetErrorString(err) );
      if (exitOnError) {
        exit(-1);
      }
  }
}

void cleanupCuda( void ) {
  //
  // Clean up CUDA resources.
  //

  //
  // Explicitly cleans up all runtime-related resources associated with the
  // calling host thread.
  //
  HANDLE_ERROR(
         cudaThreadExit()
         );
}

__device__ double device_pow( double x, double y ) {
  //
  // Calculate x^y on the GPU.
  //
  return pow( x, y );
}

//
// PLACE GPU KERNELS HERE - BEGIN
//
__global__ void kernel_calculate_sum(double *inputArray, double *outputArray, unsigned int n){
    extern __shared__ double sdata[];
    unsigned int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
    sdata[tid] = 0;
    while(i < n){
        sdata[tid] += inputArray[i];
        i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    }
    __syncthreads();
    for(unsigned int s = blockDim.x/2; s > 0; s >>= 1){
        if(tid < s){
            sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }
    if(tid == 0){
        outputArray[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
    }

}

//
// PLACE GPU KERNELS HERE - END
//

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  //
  // Determine min, max, mean, mode and standard deviation of array
  //
  unsigned int array_size, seed, i;
  struct timeval start, end;
  float runtime;

  if( argc < 3 ) {
    printf( "Format: stats_gpu <size of array> <random seed>\n" );
    printf( "Arguments:\n" );
    printf( "  size of array - This is the size of the array to be generated and processed\n" );
    printf( "  random seed   - This integer will be used to seed the random number\n" );
    printf( "                  generator that will generate the contents of the array\n" );
    printf( "                  to be processed\n" );

    exit( 1 );
  }

  //
  // Get the size of the array to process.
  //
  array_size = atoi( argv[1] );

  //
  // Get the seed to be used
  //
  seed = atoi( argv[2] );

  //
  // Make sure that CUDA resources get cleaned up on exit.
  //
  atexit( cleanupCuda );

  //
  // Record the start time.
  //
  gettimeofday( &start, NULL );

  //
  // Allocate the array to be populated.
  //
  double *array = (double *) malloc( array_size * sizeof( double ) );

  //
  // Seed the random number generator and populate the array with its values.
  //
  srand( seed );
  for( i = 0; i < array_size; i++ )
    array[i] = ( (double) rand() / (double) RAND_MAX ) * MAXIMUM_VALUE;

  //
  // Setup output variables to hold min, max, mean, and standard deviation
  //
  // YOUR CALCULATIONS BELOW SHOULD POPULATE THESE WITH RESULTS
  //
  double min = DBL_MAX;
  double max = 0;
  double sum = 0;
  double mean = 0;
  double stddev = 0;

  unsigned int threadsPerBlock = 512;
  unsigned int blocksPerGrid = (65535 < (array_size + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock)?65535:(array_size + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;

  double *dev_input_array, *dev_output_array, *outputArray;
  outputArray = (double*)malloc( blocksPerGrid * sizeof(double) );


  //
  // CALCULATE VALUES FOR MIN, MAX, MEAN, and STDDEV - BEGIN
  //
  //Allocate memory on GPU
  HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc( (void**) &dev_input_array, array_size * sizeof( double ) ) );
  HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc( (void**) &dev_output_array, blocksPerGrid * sizeof( double ) ) );
  //Copy data from host to GPU
  HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy( dev_input_array, array, array_size * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ) );
  //Execute kernel on GPU
  kernel_calculate_sum<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(dev_input_array, dev_output_array, array_size);

  //Copy data from GPU to host
  HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(outputArray, dev_output_array, blocksPerGrid * sizeof( double ), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
  for(unsigned int j = 0; j < blocksPerGrid; j++){
    sum += outputArray[j];
  }

  //Deallocate memory on GPU
  cudaFree(dev_input_array);
  cudaFree(dev_output_array);

  //
  // CALCULATE VALUES FOR MIN, MAX, MEAN, and STDDEV - END
  //

  //
  // Record the end time.
  //
  gettimeofday( &end, NULL );

  //
  // Calculate the runtime.
  //
  runtime = ( ( end.tv_sec  - start.tv_sec ) * 1000.0 ) + ( ( end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec ) / 1000.0 );

  //
  // Output discoveries from the array.
  //
  printf( "Statistics for array ( %d, %d ):\n", array_size, seed );
  printf( "    Minimum = %4.6f, Maximum = %4.6f\n", min, max );
  printf( "    Mean = %4.6f, Standard Deviation = %4.6f\n", mean, stddev );
  printf( "Processing Time: %4.4f milliseconds\n", runtime );

  //
  // Free the allocated array.
  //
  free( array );
  free(outputArray);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post all code as text in your question, with proper formating. Don't link to external sites and don't use images.

Comment: I dont know how to post text format...

Comment: If you just copy-paste the code into the box, then mark it and press ctrl+k it will be marked as code. Or you can indent by 4 spaces in the beginning of every line.

Comment: Thanks so much, i have attached it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error reported is occurring on the `cudaMemcpy` operation after your kernel call:

```
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(outputArray, dev_output_array, blocksPerGrid * sizeof( double ), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```

(in the future, its helpful to others if you identify that this is line 167 in your code)

CUDA kernel error reporting is asynchronous, so this error is actually indicating an illegal memory access in kernel code.

If you run your code with `cuda-memcheck`, you will see lots of indications like this:

```
========= Invalid __shared__ write of size 8
=========     at 0x00000068 in /.../....cu:64:kernel_calculate_sum(double*, double*, unsigned int)
=========     by thread (0,0,0) in block (0,0,0)
=========     Address 0x00000000 is out of bounds
...
```

So there is something wrong with your shared memory accesses.   When using dynamically allocated shared memory like this:

```
extern __shared__ double sdata[];
```

it is necessary to pass the size of the shared memory as a kernel parameter.  But you aren't doing so:

```
kernel_calculate_sum<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(dev_input_array, dev_output_array, array_size);
                                                     ^
                                          missing shared size parameter
```

so your shared memory accesses are failing.  A simple modification to your kernel call:

```
kernel_calculate_sum<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock, threadsPerBlock*sizeof(double)>>>(dev_input_array, dev_output_array, array_size);
```

resolves this error.  This is necessary because your kernel expects one `double` quantity per thread, so you must reserve the size of your threadblock times the size of a `double`.

Comment: Thanks so much! And i have another question is that when i run my code, the last sentence is that driver shutting down in stats_gpu.cu at line 47, is this a correct result for this program? I mean whether any cuda program showing this message? Thanks!

Comment: It's happening because of your `atexit(cleanupCuda)`...`HANDLE_ERROR(cudaThreadExit())` sequence.  It's not a problem per se, however it's generally not necessary and `cudaThreadExit()` is [deprecated](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__THREAD__DEPRECATED.html#group__CUDART__THREAD__DEPRECATED).   So most CUDA programs would not do that.  But the error itself is benign.

Comment: Ok, I got it, so it won’t affect the performance of my program, right? I appreciate your help, thanks so much again!

Comment: Hi Robert, I have a question about reduce06 in reduction document,
the following code:while (i < n) { sdata[tid] += g_idata[i] + g_idata[i+blockSize]; i += gridSize; }
__syncthreads();    will the g_idata[i+blockSize] out of the bound?  Just like that if the global array size is 256, the blockSize is 512, if i < 256, then i+512 is out of the array size, is there is null pointer exception?

Comment: This SO question isn't your personal help-desk.  If you have a new programming question, please ask a new question.

Comment: Ok, i will post a new question

Comment: I have posted another question using a 
 different account, the link is as following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49342360/cuda-reduciton-about-reduce06-in-nvida-reduction-document, if you can help, I appreciate for that.